# Android Studio xml auto completion stops after adding new Material design library widgets

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <Linea

   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

>
```

The code completion will work outside the nested scrollview.

Comment: '<Linea', I believe this is your problem? Unless a typo

Comment: i just update my android studio with cannery build because i just update my build tool it solve my problem

Comment: @LucasCrawford Sorry for not being clear. It used to autocomplete or suggest me LinearLayout when I start typing but inside the NestedScrollView it doesnot.

Comment: @mcd Tried. But not working for me.

Comment: @mcd Tried. But not working for me.
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
Android Studio 1.3 RC3

Comment: tried resetting Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem but solved by deleting `.idea` folder and `.iml` files from project, restart android studio and rebuild project.

Optionally you can try by `Invalidate caches /Restart` and also disable `Power Save Mode`.

I hope this will help you.